# Surface current density and infinite solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

I have an infinitely long cylinder with radius $R$ and axis lying on the $z-$axis, charged with volume density $\rho$ and surface density $\sigma$. The cylinder is spinning with angular velocity $\omega$, and I am asked to find the magnetic field at every point in space.

So I did realize I can treat the problem as a superposition of many infinite solenoids, but I am having a hard time calculating the field they induce. Desperately, I turned for the solution of the problem, but I couldn't understand the logic behind one thing.

The solution suggested this calculation:
$$
\vec{B} = \mu_0\int\limits_r^Rr\rho\omega\mathrm{d}r\hat{z} + \mu_0\omega R\sigma\hat{z}
$$

and it says that the integrand is the **surface** current density, derived from the volume charge density is

$$
\mathcal{J} = \frac{2\pi r\mathrm{d}r\rho\omega}{2\pi}
$$

But I couldn't understand why is this true.

Any light to pour on this? How is the surface current density related? How do I distinguish between that and the regular current density?

Thanks.

Comment: I take the cilinder is solid?

Comment: Yes the density is volume